# AngularJS Validation - ng-minlength on textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am working on a project where AngularJS is used heavily for the front-end. Here is what I have:

[image: textarea with buttons underneath]

The validation rule I want to have is as follows:

The `Next` button should be **disabled unless** the reason inputted is **at least 10 characters**.

Also, I'd like to be able to tell the user how many characters are left before he / she is able to submit. This would go in the bottom right hand corner of the textarea.

**CODE:**

```
<form name="paymentForm">
    <div class="form-group" id="Div2">
        <select ng-model="selectedPaymentStatus" ng-options="ps.name for ps in paymentStatus"></select>
    </div><!-- .form_group -->

    <div ng-show="selectedPaymentStatus.value === 'paymentDeferred'" class="form-group" id="Div3">
        <p>Reason</p>
        <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="crate.paymentDeferredReason" ng-minlength="10"></textarea>
    </div><!-- .form_group -->
</form>

<button class="btn wizard-next-btn pull-right" ng-disabled="paymentForm.$valid" ng-click="nextStep()">Next</button>
<button class="btn wizard-back-btn" ng-click="previousStep()">Back</button>
```

For some reason the above code is not working! Even when I type a single character, the next button gets enabled!

Comment: You have `ng-disabled="paymentForm.$valid"`; it should be the opposite. Also, are you sure this will work with the buttons *outside* the form?

Comment: The button seems to work outside the form; a small amendment to the above: You will also need to specify `ng-required="true"` for the empty field to be invalid; otherwise `ng-minlength` seems not to take effect on empty fields. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2JA6/)

Comment: Thanks @NikosParaskevopoulos Can you please reply as Answer? Your suggestions fixed it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make two corrections:

1. `ng-disabled="paymentForm.$valid"` should actually be `ng-disabled="paymentForm.$invalid"`
2. Add `ng-required="true"` to the `<textarea>`; otherwise `ng-minlength` seems not to take effect on empty fields.

Also the button being outside the form seems to work ok, but I would recommend against it; I have a feeling it would not work in all cases (but cannot prove it right now :)

Relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J2JA6/